# In TTTAttributedLabel two different text color not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, tttattributedlabel

I am using `TTTAttributedLabel` and set text like **"text with #tag and www.example.com"**.

My need is set **redColor** for **"www.example.com"** and **greenColor** for **"#tag"**.

But it set blue color.

**Following is my code:**

```
 [label setText:@"text with #tag and www.example.com" afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
    NSRange rangeUrl = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"www.example.com" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange rangeTag = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"#tag" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    UIFont *boldSystemFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:IS_IPAD?16:14 weight:UIFontWeightRegular];
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
    if (font) {

        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)font range:rangeUrl];
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:rangeUrl];

        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)font range:rangetag];
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range: rangeTag];
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTUnderlineColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range: rangeTag];

        CFRelease(font);
    }
    return mutableAttributedString;
}];
```

How to solve this problem.
Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way to change text color of NSMutableAttributedString

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedstring = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"text with #tag and www.example.com"];
attributedstring = [self updateString:attributedstring withChangeColorForText:@"#tag" withColor:[UIColor redColor]];
attributedstring = [self updateString:attributedstring withChangeColorForText:@"www.example.com" withColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

label.attributedText = attributedstring;
```

updateString Method:

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)updateString:(NSMutableAttributedString *)mainAttributedString withChangeColorForText:(NSString*)searchText withColor:(UIColor*) color
```

{

```
NSRange range = [mainAttributedString.string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [mainAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:color range:range];
}

return mainAttributedString;
```

}

Comment: It's working for "www.example.com" but not working "#tag".